# Is it possible to forward specific events from child components to the own parent component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a simple component raising events whenever I click on a button.

**InnerCompo.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-btn @click="emit('something-happened')">Click me</v-btn>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits<{ (e: 'something-happened'): void }>()
</script>
```

This component is consumed by a container component that doesn't care for the event **but** its own parent component does. Currently, I listen for the event and raise it again like this-

**OuterComp.vue**

```
<template>
  <inner-comp @something-happened="onSomethingHappened" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import InnerComp from "./InnerComp.vue";
  
const emit = defineEmits<{ (e: 'something-happened'): void }>()

function onSomethingHappened() {
  emit("something-happened");
}
</script>
```

The consuming parent handles the event-

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <outer-comp @something-happened="onSomethingHappened" />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import OuterComp from "./OuterComp.vue";

function onSomethingHappened() {
  console.log("something happened");
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to simplify the code in **OuterComp**?
This component needs some boilerplate code to forward the event back to its parent. I know that this component must define the emits for proper TS support but maybe there is a shorthand syntax to "bubble" the event e.g.

```
<inner-comp @something-happened.direct-forward="onSomethingHappened" />
```

For reproduction purposes- [See here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: I can't think of a simpler way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `v-bind="$attrs"`. In Vue 3, Vue events are attributes prefixed with `on`, they are no longer separately declared as `$listeners`, as in Vue 2 - documented [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html)):

OuterComp.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <inner-comp v-bind="$attrs" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    inheritAttrs: false
  }
</script>
```

`inheritAttrs: false` tells Vue not to bind attributes to the outer `<div>`. And `v-bind="$attrs"` binds them to one (or more) inner element(s), without having to specify each attribute individually.

---

Note: if you have some attributes which you want to pass and some which you don't want passed to children, you can group attributes in objects:

```html
  <inner-comp v-bind="$attrs.foo" />
```

, where `foo` is an object:

```html
  <outer-comp :foo="{ onSomethingHappened }" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice library for Vue 3 called [VueUse](https://vueuse.org/) which gives you really nice utility composables. They have a composable called `useEventBus` which you can use independent of the component structure.

#### App.vue

```js
// inside script setup
const somethingBus = useEventBus<string>('something');

const listener = (event: string) => {
  console.log(`news: ${event}`)
}

const unsubscribe = somethingBus.on(listener)
```

#### InnerComp.vue

```js
// inside script setup
const somethingBus = useEventBus<string>('something');

const handleClick = () => {
  somethingBus.emit('Some Value')
}
```

When using with typescript you can define a symbol with the type `EventBusKey` that can be used as the event bus key. See the [documentation](https://vueuse.org/core/useEventBus/) for more details